# mongoose virtual returnig undefined, how can I solve it with pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to render a table on jade, but the virtual for full name is returning undefined, can somebody please help me how to solve this.

Here is my schema, The schema stores about employees, I wanna use the virtual of fullname, that will concatenate the `first_name` and the `last_name`.

**Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        first_name: {type: String, required: true},
        last_name: {type: String, required: true},
        username: {type: String, required: true},
        email: {type:String, required: true},
        hash: {type: String},
        salt: {type: String},
        employeeid: {type: String, required: true,},
        j_date: {type: Date, },
        dep: {type: String, required: true, enum: ['Human Resources', 'Development', 'Secretary', 'Design', 'Help Desk']},
        des: {type: String, required: true}
    }
)

UserSchema
.virtual('url')
.get( function (){
    return '/employee/' + this._id;
});

UserSchema
.virtual('fullname')
.get( function () {
    return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Emp', UserSchema)
```

**Controller**
This the controller that renders the page.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const emp = require('../models/userSchema')

exports.Admin_profile_employee_get = (req, res, next) => {
    emp.find({}, 'email employeeid j_date dep des')
    .exec((err, list_employees) => {
        if(err){return next (err)}
        // Successful so render
        res.render('profile_employee', {title: 'Employee ', subtitle: ' All employees', employee_list: list_employees })        
    });
}
```

**Pug file**
That's part of my pug file which renders the table.

```
tbody
    each emp in employee_list
        tr(class = "odd")
            td(class = "sorting_1")
                h2(class = "table-avatar")
                    a(href = "#" class = "avatar")
                        img(src="/images/first-logo.png", alt="EM1")
                    a(href = "#") #{emp.fullname}
                        span #{emp.des}
            td #{emp.employeeid} 
            td #{emp.email}
            td +258 84 686 0612
            td #{emp.j_date}
    else
        h1 There are no employees
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with virtuals but have you tried to add `console.log('THIS', this)` just before the `return '/employee/' + this._id;` of the get callback function? To see if it is even called?

Comment: It seems that you need to add the props used by the virtuals to the select query `emp.find({}, '_id first_name last_name email employeeid j_date dep des')`

Comment: The callback is called, because I tried to use a string instead the `this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;` and it rendered the string on the page.